# Automate the "Creating Azure Active Directory's Application"

Tags: c#-4.0, azure, automation, azure-powershell

How do I create the Azure Active Directory and their Applications automatically?

So far I walk through on on-line to automate the Creation of Azure's Web application, Mobiles Service and other things provided by Azure account has been quit easy to create using the power shell scripts.

I have to Automate the Creation Of Azure Active Directory and their Application. I found some solution from following link.

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/06/02/azure-active-directory-graph-client-library-1-0-publish.aspx
```

Here they used **Azure Active Directory Graph Client Library 1.0** for creating and retrieve the Active Directory details. By this way, First of all we should create the 2 more new application to AD to automate this.

Instead of the above method, Is there any other possible ways available to Automate the AD Application like using Power Shell Scripts, Command Line Tool,  C# Code or Azure REST Methods to create the Application to Azure Active Directory.

Regards
Solai Raja A